# Vue Router Params with data binding

Tags: vue.js

Can anyone tell me how to use data binding inside a router param?

Trying this, but it isn't working:

```
    <router-link :to="{
        name: 'product', 
        params: {
          id: '{{product.id}}',
          title: '{{product.title}}'
        }
      }">Ring 02</router-link>
    </nav>
    <router-view/>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
  import { products } from '@/assets/data.json';

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        products
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the single quotes around {{product.id}} and {{product.title}}?

Comment: Yeah, that doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:to is a shorthand for v-bind:to, So you can access to variables and to simple expression as string, conditions, objects

```
 <router-link :to="{
        name: 'product', 
        params: {
          id: product.id,
          title: product.title
        }
      }">Ring 02</router-link>
    </nav>
    <router-view/>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
  import { products } from '@/assets/data.json';

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        products
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```